# Where in the (Stack Exchange) world can I initiate a programming-related discussion?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I fired up Stack Overflow just now and entered in the search "best jquery tooltip plugin", and was met with a fine collection of perfectly clickable candidates ... many of which have been closed as not constructive.

I've read the FAQ and I get it; it's not necessarily a factual programming question, and at some point they have to [draw a line in the sand](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118715/quotes).  Alas, I'm spoiled, and at this point I've pretty much convinced myself that if a SO post fails to generate traction then my question is untenable.

Where in the Stack Exchange universe does a question like the one above make the most sense?  Is it just flat out unacceptable anywhere?  Is there a stackdiscussion.com?  Should I be asking this in meta.stackoverflow?  [Someone kinda did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions).  But this *is* a programming question.  Factual?  debatable.  But most certainly a programming question.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Where is the code that posts your question to a stackexchange site? Where's the tag telling us which programming language you're programming your question-asker in?

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Ugh, you asked this on SO?  Shame.  Shame!  Also, I don't think these types of questions belong on SO... even though I want to ask "what X should I get to do Y" questions several times a month.  So I know the feeling.

Comment: @Won't  yes, yes.  I deserve the double shame (and the flurry of down-votes I got on SO before it was migrated)..  I was actually in here first, trolling around, but regrettably wound up back on SO and posted there.

Comment: See also: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [pointed out in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124923/where-in-the-stackexchange-world-can-i-initiate-a-programming-related-discussi#comment336281_124923), the most enlightening guidance on asking and answering *best / recommendation* type questions appears to be one given in [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

> ...consider the voluminous amount of information you need to even begin properly answering...
>
> Let’s say the question asker provided all that information. Fat chance, I know, but let’s pretend for a moment they did — and we were able to provide the perfect, ideal shopping recommendation to them. Even if that was the case, technology moves so rapidly that the best shopping recommendations will be utterly obsolete within a year! What’s the point of a bunch of labor intensive questions that provide only temporary benefit to a limited (some might say Too Localized) audience? There isn’t any...
>
> ... **there *is* a way to ask these questions that avoids the inherent problems with shopping recommendations**. For example, let’s say you wanted — as I did — to buy a point-and-shoot camera that takes good low light photos. So we’re going to ask on photo.stackexchange.com, naturally!
>
> Here’s one way to ask:
>
> > **Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?**
>
> ...Here’s another way to ask:
>
> > **Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos?**
>
> ...The former question provides the path of least resistance: a laundry list of products I can buy without thinking about it too much. But that answer will only be valid for a year at best. The latter question may take some thinking, but its answer will be valid *forever* … or at least until camera technology somehow shifts beyond lenses and sensors as we know them today. Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us *what you need to learn* to tell what you should buy...

---

Applied to your particular case, a more appropriate question could be like like "How do I tell which jquery tooltip plugin <fill in what do you want from it>"

Comment: Or take it a step further and avoid asking for a plugin at all: "How do I do X in jQuery?"

Comment: thanks.  chat is a non-starter for me here at work.  this link, and the advice was helpful.

Comment: In before "How do I tell which jquery tooltip plugin is the best jquery tooltip plugin" gets closed as not constructive.

Comment: Relating to your camera example, there is no way to tell which camera takes good pictures in low light conditions by looking just at specs. You need to test it, that is why there are so many websites doing these. And what will tell you that it needs good sensor and even better software to clean the image? Nothing.

Answer (score 18):

If you're looking for discussion instead of Q&A, I'd suggest the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

SO usually has chat rooms for specific languages/technologies, or there are some more active chatrooms that are for general chat

There's also the [Programmers.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers), which is the main chat room for [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 12):

> Where in the stackexchange universe does a question like the one above make the most sense?

Nowhere.

Stack Exchange is *not* a place for discussions or debates. The very design of SE is built around *quelling* debates should they spring up, not encouraging them out. That's why the comment system is restricted.

Stack Exchange is for answering *questions*, not discussing things and putting forth various opinions. Even subjective questions must be held to certain standards, and answers have to be backed up by either facts or actual experience.

You could try the chatrooms if you feel like it. That's as close to "discussion" as it gets.

Answer (score -4):

There's now programmers.stackexchange.com, which accepts many questions about programming projects, techniques, and designs, which aren't specific to a particular piece of code.

---

Gee, this started a firestorm.  I didn't feel there was enough information to know for sure whether the question would or would not be on-topic at Programmers.

I can't tell whether he's looking for an existing plugin (the "best" one, whatever that means) or "best practices" for writing his own plugin.

But go ahead and downvote my answer into oblivion.  I'm assuming the intent is that "this answer is not helpful" rather than incorrect, and that may be true, depending on what kind of question the user was really asking.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Programmers.SE. "Best" questions are all "bad subjective".

Comment: Oh dear, I think Mark Trapp is coming for you now....

Comment: @AdamRackis: [Not anymore.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/no-more-chairman-mao-reincarnate)

Comment: You must be new here, Ben. Any time Programmers is recommended as the place for a question, the Programmers.SE mafia comes out to downvote you into oblivion and leaves angry, fist-shaking comments that their site is not the place for that. It makes everyone a little bit confused about what, exactly, Programmers.SE *is* for, and their FAQ doesn't help. But no matter, they've successfully deterred anyone from ever recommending their site as the place for questions.

Comment: @CodyGray What parts of the FAQ are confusing? I'm not sure how saying "discussions aren't appropriate on Programmers" (which is normal for SE in general) is equivalent to "Programmers mafia" coming down on you.

Comment: @Anna - I think a certain ex-mod over there may have left some people with a bad impression of P.SE

Comment: @Anna: Ben's answer says nothing about discussions. As far as I understand the scope of Programmers, everything it says is precisely correct. But that's precisely the problem: I *don't* seem to understand the scope. This is a much more general problem. No one is arguing that we should have more discussions.

Comment: @CodyGray Fair enough, but is an answer getting downvotes cause it's making a poor recommendation worth the "Programmers is bad" rhetoric? If you have recommendations for making the FAQ there clearer, I'm sure they'd be quite receptive to that.

Comment: @AdamRackis Perhaps. FWIW, I've never seen Mark say anything on the subject that I wouldn't say (even if my wording would at times be different :)).

Comment: @Anna - your wording would have been *much* different - that's the whole point :)

Comment: @Anna: I didn't say it was "bad". I said you must be new here; no one recommends Programmers anymore because it's unclear what the site's scope is and some of its users disagree strongly with what others of its users *think* the site's scope entails. It's not a problem with the FAQ, it's a problem with the disconnect between the community at large and the moderators (not just those with diamonds). And no, I don't have any recommendations for the FAQ because I don't even understand it myself. I've followed lots of discussions about it and never seen any consensus.

Comment: @Anna - last I saw, the PSE community was really trying to *close* a lot of broken windows so people like me wouldn't swing by the site and see them active on the front page, and (honestly) get the wrong impression about the site.  Completing that process will I think go a long way

Comment: @CodyGray I definitely agree with you. The [site name doesn't match the FAQ](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2948/1130), so users not familiar with the site think it is about one thing, while those familiar with the site think it's about another. And since the site was originally created to be something other than what it is now, there is a 3rd group that disagrees with the site's direction completely. I plan on posting a meta question about changing the FAQ significantly sometime soon once I find time to finish writing it, and will outline what is unclear in the current FAQ there.

Comment: @Adam: I suppose that explains why, when I looked at the front page yesterday, over 3/4 of the questions had "[closed]" appended to their titles (I was bored; no new questions on Meta). Maybe *eventually* that will help clarify things for users; I was, however, quite confused.

Comment: @CodyGray the point is that without a lot of extra information on what the OP is trying to do it will just get a list of everyone's favourite plugin which is the very definition of not constructive. However, by adding enough qualifiers you'll either make it too localised or find the answer yourself.

Comment: @CodyGray Bad timing. We are cleaning up career related questions, at some points these past few days all our questions in the front page were closed. There are about 100 of them left, out of about 500, so we will be over soon, and our front page won't be such a mess. Needless to say, Programmers is not about career advice...

Comment: @BenVoigt It seems to me that you aren't very far off from what Programmers is actually about. We do welcome questions about programming projects, techniques, and designs, which aren't specific to a particular piece of code, the down votes you are getting are  because "best jquery tooltip plugin" is not a question that would be constructive even on jQuery Stack Exchange, if such a site existed.

Comment: @AdamRackis If you are still unsure what Programmers is about, we are about exactly the same things as Stack Overflow, from a higher perspective. Think of us as software development Stack Exchange minus implementation & development tools questions. Software development is not limited to coding, for everything else Programmers is where you should be asking.

Comment: @CodyGray: The way I keep it straight is--When I'm sitting at my keyboard, I'm on StackOverflow.  When I'm standing at the whiteboard, I'm on Programmers.

Comment: @Yannis: The test of a career-related question has always been whether someone in a similar field could ask an identical question.  For example, there have been some excellent ethics questions regarding programmers requested by their boss to falsify the version control history or other software logs.  Are those no longer welcome?

Comment: @BenVoigt However interesting & useful, these questions proven to be more trouble than they are worth, so unfortunately they aren't welcome on Programmers any more. Your example is a general workplace issue, hopefully the [Workplace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace?referrer=eeaqg1pbrZqJS6wd42Y-3w2) will grow to become a great site for these questions. Our current test for career related questions is whether they require the unique expertise of software developers, if not then they don't belong on Programmers.

Comment: @Yannis - your comment to me should be the FAQ.  It doesn't get any clearer than that.

Comment: @AdamRackis Well I think my comment is just a summation of the FAQ, and the vast majority of active P.SE users don't seem to think there's anything confusing in there... Give it a read, and if it's still confusing, consider posting a question on P.SE Meta.

Comment: @YannisRizos - the faq is pretty good, but I'd say your comment, and **especially** Wont's follow up would make for a great summary.  Just a thought :)

Comment: @Yannis: I suppose the example I mentioned is not precisely unique to software developers, since our IT colleagues would be included, but it is also not a generic question applicable to all career fields.  And sorry, I had meant "the test has been whether someone in a *dissimilar* field could ask an identical question".

Comment: @Yannis: If "more trouble than they are worth" is the standard, I think that applies to Programmers, too. I haven't seen very many questions that you still endorse as being on-topic for your site that I couldn't ask on Stack Overflow with minimal modifications. Good questions about programming are good questions. Not all questions on SO require code.

Comment: @CodyGray Here's my [FAQ suggestions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3301/1130) for Programmers. Go vote for the changes if you agree!