# Is there a StackExchange site where question about LAMP architecture will fit

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I thought that I had asked my question appropriately on Server Fault, but quite a number of people disagreed. I've been looking through all the SE sites and their respective FAQ, but it seems like I'm prohibited from asking anywhere, which is unfortunate because the SE sites have some exceptionally helpful users.

My question is about the architecture of a LAMP server that would be most suitable for an application I would like to develop.

Thanks for looking at my question. Hopefully this question is in the right place, otherwise I think I'm just going to quietly delete all my SE accounts and stick to looking at cat pictures :(

Comment: you might be interested in studying answer in this question: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in). There are a bunch of SE sites listed, along with explanation of what kind questions are welcome there

Comment: gnat, the link did help me quite a bit, but unfortunately, I think that my question is not appropriate for any of the listed sites, which are more about programming than about appropriateness of software, from what I gather.

Comment: I feel like the content of the question is appropriate for ServerFault, but the context of the question makes it not. Should I just not add any context and ask as if I were creating a webhost (as one of the potential users of my potential software?)

Comment: @gjr No, you should not. SE sites are not generally "recommendation engines". Without context, questions like that are nebulous and not useful to anyone (including yourself). With context, they become *too localized*, and not helpful to anyone else *but* you - while still probably not being useful to you because the people answering still don't know enough to answer intelligently.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I see. It's very unfortunate because there are many specific questions on SF that have remarkably good answers. I suppose I disagree with the principal of not asking my question because I'm most likely the only one who benefits, but if that is the foundation of SE, then I will respect that. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @gjr Specificity is very much *good*. I am just saying it does not help in the case of subjective questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I suppose then we disagree on the subjectiveness of the question. Regardless, you have provided the perspective I needed on the question and I will be better prepared for the future. Thank you.

Comment: if I understand correctly you look for something like guidance on improving shopping-like questions. Jeff Atwood covered this in one of SE blog articles (doesn't look like an easy job mind you). If you're interested, you can find link to article and its summary in my [answer to another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/165773)

Comment: @gnat Another good link; thank you. I think the lesson here is that I don't have a good idea of my question, therefore it cannot be answered. However, in my case I can't really narrow it down any further or else the answer would not be helpful. I think I will do some of my own testing instead. It will probably be much more insightful at any rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question sounds a bit too subjective for any SE site. "Most Suitable" is going to be entirely based on your own requirements, skills, and a dozen other factors we won't be privy to. "Just use what you know" is the best answer you can get.

The upshot of that is that this sort of question is never helpful to anyone else, because their situation is always different.

Comment: If I narrow the question down based on the range of pageviews, the type of content being served, and a few hardware guidelines, do you think this question would be less subjective? I'm looking more for what categories of software would be installed than anything else, so I thought the question was fairly easily answered.