# Why was this question about protecting a website from reverse engineering closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640125/protecting-a-website-against-reverse-engineering) closed?

It was closed about 5 minutes after asking. I can accept if I ask a wrong or inappropriate question which gets closed, but I wish to understand what led people to close this one.

My question was definitely to the topic. It was clearly written. I believe, everyone, who has ever put a lot of effort into developing a website has asked himself this question.

Comment: _"What are the options when protecting HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and the whole Website content against code stealing and reverse engineering?"_ sounds like a shopping question. It might [take some effort to tune it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/165773 "look here for guidance if you're interested") into the kind that is welcome at SE network

Comment: Would you feel better if it been closed as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124063/protecting-client-side-logic-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060984/how-can-i-encrypt-javascript-code-so-that-its-not-decryptable
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838908/how-to-protect-hide-javascript-method-or-js-file-from-user-to-view
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766834/how-do-i-protect-javascript-files

Comment: ... also note that just because these questions didn't get closed don't take it to mean that yours shouldn't have been [Stack Overflow is not a perfect model of its guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128575/148672)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter, hi thanks for your respnse. Does it mean, that the true reason, why the question got closed was, that some people do not like the idea of protecting their content? This is even more disappointing, as a person should be able to freely ask on this topic too. Thanks for your answer, anyway.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori I think the problem is that this question comes up quite frequently. It even has a [Thick-client version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4803577/119477). People generally don't like [questions that get asked a lot](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=How+do+you+protect+Javascript&oq=How+do+you+protect+Javascript&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...136.136.0.326.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.9Y-EadVOhw4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95c2cca83de3aed3&biw=1057&bih=650) , especially when the answer is *it is not technologically possible to achieve*.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori, to an extent I think you're right -- this question was closed with rather more prejudice than usual because asking how to prevent HTML from being reverse engineered is like asking how to put toothpaste back in the tube.

Comment: @KirkWoll, hi Kirk. Thanks for the answer. Whatever, this message was deleted, and I do not wish to put any more energy into it. I still think, it was correct to ask it. Even if there is no way of protecting HTML, who can be 100% sure, that anybody in the world did not invent a way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the options ...

This is likely asking for suggestions, personal opinions, which are not welcome on Stack Exchange.

Additionally, your "question" is not question but questions. They should be separated (HTML, javascript, CSS). All of them have different options

Comment: @Marting, thanks for your attempt to answer. But asking what options are to do one thing or the other is clear question an can be answered  scientifically. Option 1...., Option 2...., Option 3..... . Regarding mixing HTML, JavaScript, CSS, they all relate so closely, that it is not possible to separate them, in regards protecting a website. This is why we have **web-development** discussion topic in Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori: We're actually trying to get rid of the [tag:web-development] tag.