# Why are constructive questions being closed as "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I can't understand why on SO questions like "which framework should I use" are being closed.

For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057574/recommendations-for-a-java-backend-framework-for-html5-mobile-applications

Someone quite precisely defines requirements about framework but the question is still closed as "not constructive". For me it's constructive and I'd like to find answer for that question :/

Anyway, if that current policy is to close questions where someone can state own opinion I found whole tag of questions that can be closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-frameworks

Update:
So it seems to me that I asked wrong questions. Instead of asking why such question is closed, I should have asked "why FAQ says those questions should be closed". Number of issues with keyword closed-question clearly states that casual users do need and want such questions to be on SO. For me it seems moderators try to do something good but what they actually do in such cases only annoys people. That's especially annoying when a question, which is being closed could be easily rephrased so it would follow the rules and still "ask" same question. For instance let's say I ask "which framework is best for (...)" which is bad, but instead of this question I might write: "I am developing something, it takes me very long time, is there a tool to make it faster and easier"? and that I guess would be ok :/

Comment: Sorry, but I find that question very unconstructive; it is still a shopping question, that will be outdated quickly and only will attract personal preferences as answers.

Comment: Thank you for finding that list of questions to close (*well, it appears most are closed already*).

Comment: You should read what SE defines as "constructive" before you claim something is constructive. It's right in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: A lot of the `[web-frameworks]` questions asking for recommendations or opinions already are closed.

Comment: @Yawus a shortened version is also already in the close message

Comment: @BenBrocka And yet the user still claims the question is constructive. Some people may not look at the close message (since the close event doesn't prompt a notification in the inbox) and a more direct approach (like a comment or answer which appear in their inbox) is needed.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you, but me (and probably many more people) consider definition of word "constructive" coming from English dictionary a little bit more important than the one form SO FAQ.

Comment: "constructive" needs to be looked at contextually. Just citing a dictionary doesn't mean the nuance fits.

Comment: I know its and old debate, but it seems odd to many people that useful questions and answers are closed as not constructive (and continue to get upvotes).  And a perfectly valid question like this one gets 19 downvotes.

Answer (score 8):

You're asking broad question that'd solicit poll-style personal preference answers. Narrowing specifics of you task might change it to valid "what is a good tool for this particular job"? It is like asking "what tools to use to build house" vs. "what tools to use to put painting on a wall"?

In that case it's also better to split one broad question into several small very specific ones - you might get answers on parts much faster than on a whole mess and there will be more users benefiting from specific answers to specific questions that might arise in their development too, while I doubt someone will develop something exactly to your spec and benefit from one gigantic answer if it ever arrives.

Comment: Asking about building houses on Stack Overflow is not constructive.

Comment: And how would I split question like "which framework to use" into few smaller ones?

Comment: @Ancymon you might be interested in guidance on asking and answering _best / recommendation_ type questions [explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/165773). "...don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy..."

Answer (score 7):

How will getting a list of everyone's favourite framework/language/IDE/text editor/ice cream flavour help **you** make a decision on which one to choose?

We don't know whether you like strawberry or raspberry so getting these as an answer won't help, it'll just result in a list of all the ice cream flavours.

Adding enough information to narrow it down ("I don't like raspberry or chocolate") will only serve to make the question too localised as any answer won't help future visitors who do happen to like raspberry and chocolate.

Comment: Narrowing can be done with breaking down, not only with adding information.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - true, but you covered that in your answer :)

Comment: I'd like strawberry please...

Comment: I don't eat sweets.

Comment: Mostly because good answers on such question compare different flavors and are objective. Good answers are upvoted so that way I know which ones I might consider.

Comment: @Ancymon - while *good* answers might be objective, they are very few and far between - which is why it's far simpler to not allow the questions in the first place.

Comment: @Ancymon also, whilst the answer might be objective, people reading it would be like "STRAWBERRY?!? I LOVE STRAWBERRY!!! <Upvote> which would be subjective