# Where can I ask for help purchasing and building a computer?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask the following questions somewhere on Stack Exchange. Where can I ask this type of question?

> I am trying to build a new system for playing MMORPGs at maximum
>   capacity.
>
> I am configuring a brand new system and am spec-ing out the
>   motherboard, CPU, GPU (graphics card), memory, storage (SSD and HDD),
>   and monitor, keyboard, and mouse.
>
> So, can anyone tell me:
>
> 1. What are the operating specs (NOT minimum or recommended requirements)?  Meaning, what is the top FPS, Hz, resolution, refresh
>      rate I should look for a good system to have?
> 2. Motherboard:  best which will support multiple pin sets (i.e., upgradeable)
>             I am leaning towards a ASUS ATX Z-97A
> 3. CPU:  Intel or AMD?
>             I am leaning towards a  6th generation Intel Core i7-6700 3.4 GHz processor
> 4. GPU:  nVidia or Radeon?
>             I am leaning towards the nVidia GeForce GTX 970 or 980 GPU with 4GB 256-bit GDDR5 on-board memory and SLI for two cards
> 5. Memory?
>             I am leaning towards 16GB of 2133 MHz DDR4 RAM (but have no idea if that's good, better, or best, or if there are other options)
> 6. Storage?
>             I have several USB hard drives for external storage so I'm not sure I really care if the system comes with a 1 or 2TB HDD at 7200rpm,
>      but my main concern is the SSD -- which BRAND is best and what size
>      min is best?  256GB?
> 7. Monitors?
>             I am slightly confused about all the specs on monitors:  60Hz vs 144Hz refresh rate?, response time (GTG) under 5ms?, TN (120-144Hz)
>      or IPS (60Hz) or VA? 1080p vs 1440p?
> 8. Keyboard?
>             I like the RAZER BLACKWIDOW CHROMA or ULTIMATE 2016, the  CORSAIR VENGEANCE K70 RGB, and the LOGITECH WIRELESS ILLUMINATED
>      KEYBOARD K800.  Other suggestions?
> 9. Mouse?        RAZER DEATHADDER or NAGA CHROMA?  LOGITECH G502 PROTEUS CORE? MadCatz?  RocCat?

Comment: You seem to have taken the [tour]. Then why did you ask this question here?

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. OP does seem to ask where to ask.

Comment: Oh. Ignored the hint @Nica. Now there goes another declined flag, dammit.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. You may consider getting 3k ;)

Comment: This was not at all a site recommendation question before Mat's edit, @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. It just had an apologetic remark to that effect. You were right to flag.

Comment: @Josh Maybe you're right, but OP's added the site-recommendation tag.

Answer (score 13):

This is appropriate for [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). **However**, it is not appropriate in the current form.

As it stands this is a very broad question. We prefer to have each component listed as a separate question. This allows us to focus on just that aspect of the build. It also prevents the nearly infinite combinations that can occur for something this broad.

We do need more details and I suggest you look at our [guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality). A simple "Which is better?" is **not** ok. But, if you've narrowed it down to two and you have a list of requirements you want your hardware to meet, we can help. We need to know why you've narrowed it to these particular components and what aspect you aren't sure if they will fulfill (ie. can video card 1 and video card 2 both run a specific game at Ultra settings without stability issues).

Finally, question 1 is not OK. That is a technical support question. Number 7 may be accepted as a pre-purchase question. I can't say for sure until you've posted it as a full question. It could easily fall into technical support, so be careful.

Comment: Some good guidance on asking recommendation-type questions on SE in general: [gnat's answer where he describes what he likes to call the "Atwood's transform"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124923/where-in-the-stack-exchange-world-can-i-initiate-a-programming-related-discuss/124930#124930).